# How to create regular graph with dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I've started using dc.js today, and I managed to create almost every graph I wanted which on one axis has data from data set, and on other axis it has data calculated from other data (counts, sums etc). But now I can't for the life of me figure out how to create regular graph in dc.js which on one axis has column from original data set, and on other axis has another column from original data set, and maintaining the whole zooming feature of dc.js and crossfilter.

Comment: Your dimension is the first column and you reduce sum by the second column... It just so happens that there will only be one entry in each bin, because the first column is unique (or should be, based on your description). Does this help?

Comment: yeah, I figured it along the way, but thanks all the same man :)